# XML handling in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I've created application that generates xml files. I've used xsd tool to create model form xsd and everything works fine. But I've encountered problem. Xsd schemas are changing and when it does somebody need to regenerate model in application programatically. 
My question is: Is there any 'proper' way in C# to handle such situation: I create some folder in app to put there xsd file for application to detect it and make it require to fill all the fields that are needed in xml ?

Example:

```
        <xsd:element name="elem_name">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:simpleContent>
                    <xsd:extension base="tns:Elem_name">
                        <xsd:attribute name="A" type="xsd:string" use="required" fixed="VALUE (6)"/>
                        <xsd:attribute name="B" type="xsd:string" use="required" fixed="VALUE_1"/>
                        <xsd:attribute name="C" type="xsd:token" use="required" fixed="Z"/>
                        <xsd:attribute name="D" type="xsd:string" use="required" fixed="2-0E"/>
                    </xsd:extension>
                </xsd:simpleContent>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

<elem_name A="VALUE (6)" B="VALUE_1" C="Z" D="2-0E">value</elem_name>
```

After:

```
        <xsd:element name="elem_name">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:simpleContent>
                    <xsd:extension base="tns:Elem_name">
                        <xsd:attribute name="A" type="xsd:string" use="required" fixed="VALUE (7)"/>
                        <xsd:attribute name="B" type="xsd:string" use="required" fixed="VALUE_2"/>
                        <xsd:attribute name="C" type="xsd:token" use="required" fixed="Z"/>
                        <xsd:attribute name="D" type="xsd:string" use="required" fixed="3-0E"/>
                    </xsd:extension>
                </xsd:simpleContent>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

<elem_name A="VALUE (7)" B="VALUE_2" C="Z" D="3-0E">value</elem_name>


public partial class elem_name {

    private string A;
    private string B;
    private string C;
    private string D;

    private elem_name valueField;

    public elem_name () {
        this.A= "VALUE (7)";
        this.B= "VALUE_1";
        this.C = "Z";
        this.D = "2-0E";
    }
    ....getters/setters
  }
```

Or

```
        <xsd:element name="variant">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:byte">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="6"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>

<variant>6</variant>
```

for

```
        <xsd:element name="variant">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:byte">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="7"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>

<variant>7</variant>
```

Thing that can change:

- fixed values will change in every new version, document\schema version, some predefined field values

- it didn't occured yet but I think xml structure can also change, some fields can be removed or added

Comment: can you add snippets of an actual change in the xml file ... before and after to get a better grip of the problem. + one model class

Comment: XSD schemas are there to define the XML structure for some longer time. (Until the next version becomes necessary). If you find yourself changing the XSD frequently, then you probably have a _deeper_ desing issue and should tackle your task in a different way.

Comment: What do you mean by 'xsd schemas are changing'? If you manually generated them using xsd.exe then they won't change unless your source xml contains DTD or schema reference. If the xml's are generated by your app solely then you could add versioning.

Comment: I've added snippets. What I mean by 'xsd schemas are changing' is schemas are issued by government agecny and it usually change year by year. I don't need to do this better that it is now as appliaction works fine but i would like to make it better.